# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, bundle

I am trying to install acts_as_commentable_with_threading. I have added "gem 'acts_as_commentable_with_threading'" to my Gemfile.

When I run "bundle install" from the command line I get the following.

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    acts_as_commentable_with_threading depends on
      activerecord (~> 3.0.0)

    rails (= 3.1.0) depends on
      activerecord (3.1.0)
```

So acts_as_commentable_with_threading won't work with activerecord 3.1.0? I am not sure how to workaround this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can't work around it, because `acts_as_commentable_with_threading` is dependent using `~> 3.0.0` which means `>= 3.0.0` but `< 3.1` *(ref: http://gembundler.com/rationale.html - section **"Updating a Dependency"**)*

The only options are to:

- downgrade Rails to 3.0 or
- not use this gem, because it's support is not up to date w/the lates version of activerecord, according to the author

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading/issues/19

You can use bundle update, and it will resolve the conflict.

Take it easy!

Answer (score 0):

Use the rails 3.1 version here:
https://github.com/dfischer/acts_as_commentable_with_threading